# HP DL360e G8 with P410I

Tags: raid, hp, hp-proliant, hardware-raid

Can I use a P410i RAID Controller in the HP DL360 "e" version G8 server? I currently have several G7 boxes with 410i's in them, working fine. I see listed in the QuickSpecs for the DL360"e" versions that the P420 is listed as the "performance" model - but I'm wanting to buy a refurb unit with a B120i and then upgrading to a 410. Do I need to use a 420 card instead?

Answer (score 2):

According to the matrix http://31.172.190.2:8080/cms1/dzp_zalaczniki/21774AA3-4003ENW.PDF, only P420i is officially compatible with HP Gen8 servers. I'd suggest you to use that one instead of P420i

Answer (score 0):

You should use a P420i. There are also some DL360e units equipped with P420i controllers.

I'd avoid anything with a B120i card.

Don't use a P410i (2009-2012 era) in a Gen8 (2012-2015) system.